# CSS white-space cascading incorrectly?

Tags: css, google-chrome, whitespace

I have the following basic structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="root">
        <div>Lots of text here</div>
        <div>Lots more test here</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>I should always be visible</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this CSS:

```
#root {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#root>div {
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The idea is that each of the child `<div>`s is a "page" that can be shown by a horizontal scroll.

However, although the elements do appear side-by-side, the text within seems to still be affected by the `nowrap`, despite the `normal` that should be affecting them (and according to the Inspector, is affecting them).

I have tested in IE9 (`white-space` works correctly), and Chrome 23 (`white-space` remains `nowrap`).

Is there a workaround for this, or is a (severe) bug in Chrome?

Comment: It looks the same to me in IE9(Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode IE9) and chrome 23 http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/RgbY4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's working fine in [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VTKGC/3/).

My fiddle contains your example with some lorem ipsum hucked in there to fill it out:

html:

```
<div id="root">
    <div>Lots of text here</div>
    <div>Even more text here... well, in the fiddle it's the exact same text...</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#root {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#root > div {
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, white-space is correctly set to `normal`.

[image: screenshot!]

Comment: I've finally figured out what the difference is between my page and your Fiddle: The `root` element is actually inside a table cell. Try adding `<table><tr><td>` and `</td></tr></table>` around the `root` element, and you'll see exactly the problem I'm running into. The problem can be half-fixed by adding `table-layout:fixed;width:100%` to the table, but the problem with that is that there are more than just one cell in the actual table and their width is not necessarily known (and I don't want to hard-code them). [This updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VTKGC/4/) better shows what's going on

Comment: Problem resolved by removing the table. Floating worked fine now even though it wasn't before. Answer accepted as Best Answer (or in this case "only answer" :D)

Comment: @Kolink I ran into this issue as well (Chrome v29) and this was without tables I used ul>li for an inline-block layout. Still trying to figure out a fix...